# How do I publish a tweet with media from Angular 2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, twitter-rest-api

I am working on an IONIC project with angular. I want to publish tweet to a specific twitter account from the IONIC app. How can I do that?
I tried to use https://github.com/Aoinu/ng2-twitter this NPM package, but no luck. For browser, it is giving  below error

**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).**

When I am trying from Ionic DevApp in iPhone 6, it is not giving any error but tweet is not posting.

Thanks in advance for any help.

I used below code which is calling after submit a from.

```
getHomeTimeline(){
        this.twitter.post(
            'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json',
            {
                status: 'test Tweet'
            },
            {
                consumerKey: 'consumerKey',
                consumerSecret: 'consumerSecret'
            },
            {
                token: 'My twitter token',
                tokenSecret: 'Token Secret'
            }
        ).subscribe((res)=>{
            //this.result = res.json().map(tweet => tweet.text);
            console.log(res);
            console.log('working');
        });
    }
```

Comment: what did you try already? a piece of code would be helpful

Comment: @TheHeadRush Thanks for the link which helped me to know how should I post when I need help. I updated my post accordingly.

Comment: Downvote rescinded.